# How to force http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, directive

I have the following in a .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Yet when I go to https://example.com I get an invalid certificate screen in the browser. How can I force the visitor to `http://` temporarily until the SSL Cert gets purchased and installed?

Answer (score 2):

Redirects happen on the HTTP layer with an HTTP response header. HTTP*S* encapsulates HTTP into a TLS connection; the TLS connection has to be negotiated first before interaction at the HTTP layer can happen. If your server fails to negotiate a valid TLS connection, e.g. because it cannot present a certificate the client will accept, then it also cannot redirect the client at the HTTP layer.

Comment: Ok, so in other words and in layman's terms @deceze, this cannot be accomplished?

Comment: @H.Ferrence Correct.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following Code in the .htaccess File:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

This will redirect the port request 443 (SSL) to 80 (HTTP).
I tried it out, it works fine for me.